# Kernel memory address space

Tags: windows, memory-management, x86, kernel

I've read that, on a 32-bit system with 4GB system memory, 2GB is allocated to user mode and 2GB allocated to kernel mode. But, If I had a system with 512 MB of memory, would it be partitioned as 256 MB to user and 256 MB to kernel address space?

Comment: Where did you read this?  Because, on 32-bit Windows (pre-Win7), you can only use a maximum of 3GB of memory.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx for more details.

Comment: @David: These are physical memory limitations. Virtual address space is always 4GB on a 32-bit system.

Comment: I was under the impression that "system memory" refers to  physical RAM on the system.  I say that because this is all the memory one could identify if an OS was absent.

Comment: Actually I referred "system memory" as physical RAM in my question but I didn't know it was virtual memory on HDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing physical and virtual memory. 2GB is allocated to user/system, but it is virtual memory. It is even more correct to say that they are not rather allocated but they constitute an addressing space. Initially this space is not bound to physical memory at all. When application actually needs memory (first time is at start up) physical memory is allocated and some addresses from address space are mapped to it. When memory is allocated but not used long enough or PC is running out of physical memory data can be dumped in swap file, and stay there until requested. This mapping is transparent for application and it has no idea where data currently is: on chip or on HDD. So the address space is always splitted the same way.

Comment: But I've virtual memory limited to say `765 MB` where does it allocate 4 GB of memory?

Comment: @user32344 for every process regardless of amount of physical memory size of virtual address space (virtual memory) is 4Gbs. it can't be `765 MB`  and even `4765 MB` for 32 bit system. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space

Comment: If I ran out of disk space, how would it compensate?

Comment: It would pretend that the disk was RAM. As you may imagine this has significant impact on performance. You need to look up the Wikipedia page on virtual memory.

Comment: @user32344 your system will show start throwing errors and crash if you don't close apps.

Comment: I also confused total amount of virtual memory with `765 MB` of paging file size in windows settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about memory (physical or virtual), but about address space.

You can plug 16GB of physical memory into your computer and make a 100GB swapfile, but 32-bit (non-enterprise) Windows will still only see 4GB (and subtract 0.75 GB for GPU memory and such). Via PAE, it could use more, but non-enterprise versions won't do that.

On top of the *actual* amount of memory, there is address space, which is limited to 4GB as well. Basically it is no more and no less than the collection of "numbers" (which, in this case, are addresses) that can be represented by a 32 bit number.
Since the kernel will need memory too, there is some arbitrary line drawn, which happens to be at the 2GB boundary for 32bit Windows, but can be configured differently, too.

It has *nothing* to do with the amount of memory on your computer (virtual or phsyical), but it is a limiting factor of how much memory you can use within a single program instance. It is *not*, however, a limiting factor on the memory that several programs could use.

Answer (score 0):

[As far as I can tell, what you are referring to are *limits* of how much memory *can* be allocated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This is much different than how much memory the OS allocated during runtime.

Comment: A system can allocate more memory than is physically present. When that happens it comes from the page file.